# Создание триггера по типу cron-демона

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Существует ли возможность создания триггера для MariaDB или MySQL, который бы выполнялся с определённой периодичностью. Например, удалял записи за предыдущий день, запускаясь каждый день в 00:00?

Comment: Слова "тиггер" не существует. А "триггера" работают по действиям на таблицах и никакого отношения к вашей задаче не имеют. Искать в гугле по фразе "mysql события"

Comment: `CREATE EVENT` и выполняющая нужные действия процедура.

Comment: Да я тупой школьник -- простите мне мою невнимательность. Спасибо, загуглил - разобрался.

Comment: @Mike, я вчера индекс добавил -- все работает отлично, но только на коротких промежутках времени - до 4х часов. Если промежуток больше, то запрос  становится более 5 секунд. А мне, помимо часа и четырёх, нужны результаты за сутки, неделю и месяц. Я решил сделать промежуточную таблицу, в которую записывать результаты "тяжёлых" запросов, которые периодически запускать кроном. Ну и соответственно пользователю отдавать данные из неё. А короткие промежутки - брать из основной. Это верное решение?

Comment: В принципе да. Можно накапливать в такой таблице например статистику за каждый час. и потом уже по ней нужное кол-во часов будут быстро суммироваться. причем можно все завершившиеся часы брать из нее и добавлять последний час по основной таблице

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас так и сделаю.